# how to open external url in iframe which has X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to open an external URL in a frame inside of a modal pop up  but that URL has X-Frame-Options set to Same-origin.
Is there any way to  achieve this ?
Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: It is impossible. That's the point of SAMEORIGIN.

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding a different "X-Frame-Options" in the page you are embedding your iframe in.

X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: no that's not working   <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content = "ALLOW-FROM url">

Comment: Setting the meta tag is useless! For instance, <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> has no effect. Do not use it! Only by setting through the HTTP header , X-Frame-Options will work.